# pgAdmin 4: Cannot open public schema "Tables" after upgrading to Win11

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, pgadmin-4, windows-11

I am hosting a PostgreSQL 9.5 database on a DigitalOcean Droplet. I am using pgAdmin 4 v6.14 to access the database server.

Since upgrading to Windows 11, I still can connect and manually query the databases, but if I try to open /Schemas/public/Tables, there is just an endless "Windows-Sweep-Waiting-Icon" without any result nor error message. Other subsections such as Sequences are seemingly working fine. Other stakeholders using Windows 11 are experiencing the same issue, while users using Windows 10 can still use pgAdmin to access the database tables.

Are there any experiences with this problem? Is "just upgrade your postgreSQL version" the way to go? I am unexperienced in hosting a postgreSQL server and since there are multiple projects currently running, I am afraid to mess up with the server while it is "basically" working, and Windows 11 seems to be the discriminant factor.

Best regards

Comment: There is no version "Postgres 9". Until 9.6, a major version was indicated by the first two digits. So there was 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5 and 9.6 (that's seven different major versions) - all of them are no longer maintained.

Comment: What version of `pgAdmin4`?

Comment: pgAdmin 6.13, updated to 6.14 but still the same issue. 
However, now I receive the error message: "ERROR: column "wait_event_type" does not exist LINE 10: wait_event_type || ': ' || wait_event AS wait_event, ^"     ... which does not tell me anything.

Edit: Ok, it seems there is no other way than upgrade the postgreSQL version. Now, I also get the warning message:   "You have connected to a server version that is older than is supported by pgAdmin. This may cause pgAdmin to break in strange and unpredictable ways. Or a plague of frogs. Either way, you have been warned! Server connected."

Comment: 1) You still have not specified the exact Postgres version you are using. 2) Can you connect using `psql`?

Comment: Sorry, I had issues connecting to the droplet. Postgres 9.5 is installed. I can connect via psql  (more precisely via sudo -u postgresql psql), can list and connect to databases and also show tables via \dt.

Comment: I had same issue & same symptoms with psql version 11 and pgAdmin 4 v6.16.
 As I couldn't upgrade pg version, i ended up by installing and using DBeaver which is working like a charm